# If I register multiple Android devices in C2DM, do I receive multiple Registration IDs

Tags: php, android, android-c2dm

Regarding C2DM, if I have a phone and another device (another phone, potentially a GoogleTV, etc) and I setup a C2DM server, will I receive two different Registration ID's that I can then use to send intents to both devices?

What seems like it may happen is this: I register one device and I receive my ID. Then I register another device and I receive a different ID which invalidates the first. Is my assumption correct?

I don't want to do a lot of development only to find out that a user's account can only have one Registration ID active at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will receive different registration IDs on each device. The Google account on the device is not used for registering with C2DM. The registration ID is used to send a notification to a particular application on a particular device.

More information about how the registration ID is constructed can be found in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-c2dm/browse_thread/thread/148da734c005aa55/967cb6833e42f67a?lnk=gst) from the `android-c2dm` Google group.

You need an active Google account on the device so that the transport underlying C2DM is active (the same mechanism is used by Google for Gmail and Market notifications).

Comment: This is seriously helpful. Thanks.